# How to implement automatic color change in matplotlib with subplots?

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, subplot

I am drawing charts with matplotlib. When i am drawing it at the same chart with this code:

```
def draw0(x, ys, labels):


    plt.suptitle("big title")

    i =0
    for y in ys:
        plt.plot(x, y, label=labels[i])
        plt.scatter(x, y)  # dots
        plt.xticks(range(1, max(x) + 1))
        plt.grid(True)
        i+=1

    plt.figlegend(loc="upper left")

    plt.show()

    return

x = [1,2,3,4,5]
y1 = [1,3,5,7,9]
y2 = [10,30,50,70,90]
y3 = [0.1,0.3,0.5,0.7,0.9]

draw0(x, [y1, y2, y3], ["chart1", "chart2", "chart3"])
```

everything works fine.
[charts in one window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qR8sx.png)
But i need each chart to be at the separate subplot.

I am trying to do it like this:

```
def draw11(x, ys, labels):

    plt.figure()

    plt.suptitle("big title")

    i =0
    for y in ys:
        if i == 0:
            ax = plt.subplot(len(ys),1, i+1)
        else:
            plt.subplot(len(ys), 1, i + 1, sharex=ax)
        plt.plot(x, y, label=labels[i])
        plt.scatter(x, y)  # dots
        plt.xticks(range(1, max(x) + 1))
        plt.grid(True)
        i+=1

    plt.figlegend(loc="upper left")

    plt.show()

    return
```

I am getting this.

[charts in sublots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/13PnN.png)

Issue is that all charts have the same color. And legend is useless.
How i can add **automatic** color management for all sublots? I'd like to have not the same colors there.
Like subplot1.chart1 = color1, subplo1.chart2 = color2, sublot2.chart1 = color3, not color1.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Matplotlib has a built-in property cycler, which by default has 10 colors in it to cycle over. However those are cycled per axes. If you want to cycle over subplots you would need to use the cycler and get a new color from it for each subplot.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
colors = plt.rcParams["axes.prop_cycle"]()

def draw11(x, ys, labels):
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=len(ys), sharex=True)
    fig.suptitle("big title")

    for ax, y, label in zip(axes.flat, ys, labels):
        # Get the next color from the cycler
        c = next(colors)["color"]

        ax.plot(x, y, label=label, color=c)
        ax.scatter(x, y, color=c)  # dots
        ax.set_xticks(range(1, max(x) + 1))
        ax.grid(True)

    fig.legend(loc="upper left")
    plt.show()


x = [1,2,3,4,5]
y1 = [1,3,5,7,9]
y2 = [10,30,50,70,90]
y3 = [0.1,0.3,0.5,0.7,0.9]

draw11(x, [y1, y2, y3], ["chart1", "chart2", "chart3"])
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. It looks like a solution i was looking for. I thought it is possible to somehow set the same color cycler to each subplot, but this solution will work too for me. Could you tell me, will next() loop colors from last one to first one at the end of 'colors'?

Comment: (1) The same color cycler *is*  actually present in each axes, but it's not the same instance of the cycler; I think internally a copy of it is used. Hence each axes will start it at the first element. (2) Yes, it's not `next` that'll do it, but the cycler is really a cycler in the sense that `next(c)` will give you the first element once you've reached the end.

Comment: Basically the same answer I provided but instead of using costum colors this uses matplotlib default color list. You still have to specify the list "manually" by stating `colors = plt.rcParams["axes.prop_cycle"]()`, so .@ilya your comments on my answer (given I indicated you could cycle over the list of colors) make no sense whatever.

Comment: `plt.rcParams["axes.prop_cycle"]` gets you the colors from the style sheet. If you use a different style sheet you get different colors. Also a `cycler` will cycle, so no need to care about it reaching the end. In that sense it's rather automatic, i.e. no need to type in `'#1f77b4'` or so. The reason it doesn't get more automatic than that is that from the design perspective you'd rather want to have each axes have its own cycler.

Comment: _"I think internally a copy of it is used"_ — if I have it correct, every `axes` uses the same `cycler` but a different instance of the `itertools.cycle` that `cycler_object()` returns.

Comment: As you mention _"If you use a different style sheet you get different colors."_ I'd like to add that sometimes we use a style sheet with a single (black?) color and different line widths, line styles etc.  In a similar case the default-by-style-sheet color is overrided by explicitly setting it to `'black'`, but the remaining line properties will be, _in each subplot_, following the same order.  —  Maybe you could generalize your answer by mentioning that we can pass the whole dictionary returned by `next(colors)` to the  `ax.plot(...)` command.

Comment: The question asks about color and you wouldn't want to use the cycler's linestyle for the `scatter`, right?

Answer (score 1):

Just have a list of colors and select them for each `plt.plot` and `plt.scatter`.

```
colors = ['orange', 'cyan', 'green']
i =0
for y in ys:
        if i == 0:
            ax = plt.subplot(len(ys),1, i+1)
        else:
            plt.subplot(len(ys), 1, i + 1, sharex=ax)
        plt.plot(x, y, label=labels[i], c=colors[i])
        plt.scatter(x, y, c=colors[i])  # dots
        plt.xticks(range(1, max(x) + 1))
        plt.grid(True)
        i+=1
```

Comment: Replace `c=color[i]` by `c=colors[i]`

Comment: yeap was a typo, just fixed it.

Comment: It wont work for me, since there can be more than 3 subplots. Thats why i asked about automatic color management.

Comment: And you should have included this information in the question, otherwise is misleading and a waste of time for everybody.

Comment: Please read last part of my question. Word '**automatic**'  made bold especially for such answers.

Comment: Yes, well, my answer automatically changes the color in the `for` loop. So saying automatic does not really provide very useful information because it has different meanings for different readers. The fact that is bold does not make any difference.

Comment: Ok, just to help me understand you better, could you provide solution which changes colors **manually**?

Comment: Ok. So I have provided a solution which you "manually" hard code a list of colors and the loop "automatically" picks colors from that list at every iteration. If you have `n` plot to show, create a list with `n` different colors. If that is not doable (your number of plots to create is, say, > 50) just cycle through the list from the start when n > 50. Make sense? You will have repeated colors but only after the 50th plot.

Comment: If you want I can include this cycling thing in my solution, if you really need it.