# One `figure`, many `axes`, one `prop_cycle`

Tags: matplotlib

[Answering](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53681489/2749397) the famous question [*"How to get different colored lines for different plots in a single figure?"*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4805048/2749397) I stumbled in a behavior that puzzled me...

The problem is to get different line colors in different subplots,
like this

```
In [29]: import numpy as np 
    ...: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt                                                  

In [30]: fig, axes = plt.subplots(2,1)                                                    

In [31]: for ax in axes.flatten(): 
    ...:     ax.plot((0,1), (0,1))
```

[image]

As you can see, both lines are Blue — I can understand that this happens because each `ax` has its own `prop_cycle`.

I can remedy the problem using an explicit color name

```
In [44]: fig, axes = plt.subplots(2,1)                                                    

In [45]: for ax, short_color_name in zip(axes.flatten(), 'brgkyc'): 
    ...:     ax.plot((0,1), (0,1), short_color_name)
```

[image]

but if I try to reuse the same `cycler` object...

```
In [47]: my_cy = plt.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle']                                          

In [48]: for ax in axes.flatten(): 
    ...:     ax.set_prop_cycle(my_cy) 
    ...:     ax.plot((0,1), (0,1))
```

I get two subplots with two Blue lines...

In my understanding, what I'd like to do is impossible because the `ax` *calls* the cycler that returns an `itertools.cycle` that in turn actually produces the `kwargs` as needed, but I ask anyway because

> There are more things in Matplotlib than are dreamt of in my philosophy.

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53521396/how-to-implement-automatic-color-change-in-matplotlib-with-subplots/53523348#53523348) what you want to do?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest More or less... As well as the poster of the question you mentioned, I'd like to delegate as much as possible to Matplotlib, but your answer is good enough. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recommendation in case you only have a single artist to style would be

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axes = plt.subplots(2,2)
cycler = plt.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle']()

for i, ax in enumerate(axes.flat):
    ax.plot((0,1), (0,1), **next(cycler))

plt.show()
```

Comment: _"in case you only have a single artist to style"_ may I ask why you say so?

Comment: If you use `**next(cycler)` for another artist in the loop, it will get the next style, which may not be wanted (though I'm not sure what's wanted here tbh.)

Answer (score 0):

Prompted by [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53681844/one-figure-many-axes-one-prop-cycle?noredirect=1#comment94221063_53681844), I'd like to propose

```
...
next_shared_style = plt.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle']().__next__
for i, ax in enumerate(axes):
    ax.plot(x, y[i], **next_shared_style())
```

where

- `plt.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle']` is a `cycler` object,
- `plt.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle']()` returns a `itertools.cycle` object and
- `next_shared_style = plt.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle']().__next__` is the `__next__` method of the `itertools.cycle` object.

Each invocation of `next(my_cycle_object_as_instantiated_by_a_cycler)` returns a dictionary of parameters, to pass correctly this dictionary to a `pyplot` plotting command we have simply to *unpack* it, as in
`plot(x, y[i], **next_shared_style())`.

Using the whole dictionary ensures that each subplot shares the same loop over *all the attributes* that are controlled by the `prop_cycle`.